# mktime convert seconds to date

Tags: php

I'm stuck on how to use mktime.  How do i get the date to when the ban will be lifted?

```
$time = strtotime($banrow['time']); //when user got banned

    //1 week

        $banduration = 60*60*24*7;
        $newtime = $time+$banduration;


        echo date('Y-m-d',mktime());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `date("Y-m-d",$newtime);` is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

use below code as example to see how it works

```
$time = mktime(11, 14, 54, 8, 12, 2014);
//mktime(hour,minute,second,month,day,year) as the right order

echo "Create time is ".date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$time);// year first
echo "<br>";
echo "Create time is ".date('d-m-Y h:i:s',$time);//day first
echo "<br>";
echo "Year is ".date('Y',$time);//Just print Year
echo "<br>";
echo "Month is ".date('m',$time);//just print month
//use date(format,optional)
//the format can be what you want it to be display
```

the output is

```
  Create time is 2014-08-12 11:14:54
  Create time is 12-08-2014 11:14:54
  Year is 2014
  Month is 08
```

?>